# What is the intersection of an event with itself?

Tags: probability, fake-proofs

The probability of the intersection of two event is:

$P(A \cap B) = P(A)P(B)$

If the two events are the same, i.e

$P(A \cap A) = P(A)P(A) = P(A)^2$

However, the logic tells us that the probability of an event intersecting itself is 1, since it is contained within itself.

So the probability must be $1$ or $P(A)^2$

Comment: A intersect A is A.  It is just P(A)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You only have that:

$P(A \cap B)=P(A)\cdot P(B)$

if $A$ and $B$ are *independent* events ... but $A$ and $A$ are clearly *not*.

However, what is *always* true is that

$P(A \cap B) = P(A) \cdot P(B|A)$

Thus, you have that:

$P(A\cap A)=P(A) \cdot P(A|A)$

But, obviously we have that $P(A|A)=1$: the probability that $A$ happens given that $A$ happens is $1$

Hence:

$P(A \cap A) = P(A) \cdot P(A|A)= P(A) \cdot 1 = P(A)$

Of course, this make total sense, since set-theoretically, we immediately have that $A \cap A=A$, and thus we could have immediately said that $P(A \cap A) =P(A)$.  But it is nice to confirm that it works out using the general formula as well. Sanity check! :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer

Comment: @Mattiu You're welcome! Remember that more general formula, because that is how you derive Bayes' Law as well!

Comment: Good answer. ${}{}$

Answer (score 2):

$P(A \cap B) = P(A)P(B)$ only if $A$ and $B$ are independent. $A$ and $A$ can hardly be so.

$P(A \cap B) = P(A)P(B|A)$ and for $B=A$,  $P(A \cap A) = P(A)P(A|A)=P(A)$, which is not much of an info.

Comment: Thanks for $P(A \cap A) = P(A)P(A|A)=P(A)$

Answer (score 1):

The stated "rule" only holds when the events are independent.  $A$ is not independent from itself.

Answer (score 1):

$P(A \cap B) = P(A)P(B)$ is **not always true**, only if $A$ and $B$ are independent.

Clearly an event is not (usually) independent of itself.

Also, it is not true that "the probability of an event intersecting itself is $1$", $P(A\cap A)=1$.  What you presumably mean is $P(A\cap A)=P(A)$.